# Why is this template literal returning all columns in separate rows?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, template-literals

I'm using Bootstrap 4 on the front end, and a simple template literal to pass my strings. It's outputting the columns into their own individual rows, and I don't understand why.

```js
const bodList = [
  {
    image: "https://placekitten.com/450/600",
    name: "First Last",
    profile: "https://www.google.com",
    termExp: "2023",
    title: "Chief Guy",
    company: "The Company"
  },
  {
    image: "https://placekitten.com/450/600",
    name: "First Last",
    profile: "https://www.google.com",
    termExp: "2023",
    title: "Chief Guy",
    company: "The Company"
  },
  {
    image: "https://placekitten.com/450/600",
    name: "First Last",
    profile: "https://www.google.com",
    termExp: "2023",
    title: "Chief Guy",
    company: "The Company"
  }
];

function bodTemplate(bod) {
  return `
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <div class="card border-0">
        <img src="${bod.image}" class="card-img-top" alt="${bod.name}">
        <div class="card-body pl-0">
          <h5 class="card-title"><a href="${bod.profile}">${bod.name}</a> <span class="text-right">${bod.termExp}</span></h5>
          <h6 class="card-title">${bod.title}</h6>
          <h6 class="card-title"><span class="text-muted font-weight-bold">${bod.company}</span></h6>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `;
}

document.getElementById("boardDirectors").innerHTML = `
  ${bodList.map(bodTemplate).join(" ")}
`;
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div id="boardDirectors"></div>        
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with template literals, it's probably a bootstrap-4 or CSS issue. Does it work correctly if you use old-fashioned string concatenation instead of templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bootstrap / CSS issue, rather anything related to the fact you've used template literals.

It appears that by having an extra `<div`> in between the `row` div and the `col` divs, you've broken the link between those two (in bootstrap's mind at least), so it doesn't treat those columns as columns. I haven't checked the source but I'd guess it's related to how the CSS rules are defined, perhaps a strict hierarchy is required.

Anyway the simple solution is to remove that div and shift the `id="boardDirectors` attribute onto the row div.

I also removed the `no-gutters` class to stop the images bunching up next to each other - now it allows some space in between them.

```js
const bodList = [
  {
    image: "https://placekitten.com/450/600",
    name: "First Last",
    profile: "https://www.google.com",
    termExp: "2023",
    title: "Chief Guy",
    company: "The Company"
  },
  {
    image: "https://placekitten.com/450/600",
    name: "First Last",
    profile: "https://www.google.com",
    termExp: "2023",
    title: "Chief Guy",
    company: "The Company"
  },
  {
    image: "https://placekitten.com/450/600",
    name: "First Last",
    profile: "https://www.google.com",
    termExp: "2023",
    title: "Chief Guy",
    company: "The Company"
  }
];

function bodTemplate(bod) {
  return `
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <div class="card border-0">
        <img src="${bod.image}" class="card-img-top" alt="${bod.name}">
        <div class="card-body pl-0">
          <h5 class="card-title"><a href="${bod.profile}">${bod.name}</a> <span class="text-right">${bod.termExp}</span></h5>
          <h6 class="card-title">${bod.title}</h6>
          <h6 class="card-title"><span class="text-muted font-weight-bold">${bod.company}</span></h6>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `;
}

document.getElementById("boardDirectors").innerHTML = `
  ${bodList.map(bodTemplate).join(" ")}
`;
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" id="boardDirectors">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not relevant to template literals. It's CSS related.

Try adding your id on the div above:

`<div id="boardDirectors" class="row no-gutters">`

and remove the old one. This should solve your issue.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="boardDirectors" class="row no-gutters"></div>
</div>
```